# Radio Button not updating value on Server Side

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have 3 radio buttons in a form which are all part of a single group. When one of the non-default radio buttons is clicked, they update on the client side properly (deselects previous radio button and selects new one). I have even attached an OnClientClick to the button that submits the form to test it and right before the form is submitted the .checked values are correct. But the first line of code that is reached on the server side checks the values, again for testing purposes, but .checked values have not changed. The default is still checked according to the server.

Here is some of my relevant code:

ASP

```
<asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rdoDays" Text=" Days" GroupName="RepeatType" />
<asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rdoMonths" Text=" Months" GroupName="RepeatType" />
<asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rdoYears" Text=" Years" GroupName="RepeatType" />

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSaveAlert" OnClick="btnSaveAlert_OnClick" 
     Text="Save" OnClientClick="Test()" />
```

Javascript - when month is clicked, the javascript shows "False" then "True" for the alert boxes as it should.

```
function Test() {
    var rdoDays = document.getElementById("<%= rdoDays.ClientID %>");
    var rdoMonths = document.getElementById("<%= rdoMonths.ClientID %>");
    var rdoYears = document.getElementById("<%= rdoYears.ClientID %>");
    alert(rdoDays.checked);
    alert(rdoMonths.checked);
}
```

Then for the C#, I have set a breakpoint in VS at the very beginning of Page_Init and the radio button .checked values are all "false"

I have no idea what's going on. Am I missing a tag in the asp element or something? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I ended up changing to use a telerik:RadButton as a toggle control instead of using an asp:RadioButton. This provided the server with updated values upon postback. Not really an answer to the question as much as an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Viewstate is loaded in between OnInit and OnLoad.  Try checking to see if the radio button  is checked in the OnLoad event of the page.

Comment: Its not. The value in .Checked doesn't change between the Init function and OnLoad.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use Fiddler to test to see what data is being sent from your client to your server to try to narrow down where the actual problem is:

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: I downloaded Fiddler. After running it and causing a Postback, I looked through the WebForm tab to see what was being sent to the server and it appears as though the radio buttons themselves are not being sent. But the Group is being sent with a value of "rdoMonth"